# Rails doesn't reconize application.html.haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration

Versions> ruby 1.9.2p290 , Rails 3.1.0 , Ubuntu 12.04

My RoR app doesn't detect application.html.halm . So the HTML tags are not being interpreted and de CSS and other common files aren't being included. The rest of the views are rendered in halm and are working :)

Here my Application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
end
```

Movies controller

```
# This file is app/controllers/movies_controller.rb
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
  end

  def show
    id = params[:id]
    @movie = Movie.find(id)
    # will render app/views/movies/show.html.haml by default
  end
  def new
    # default render 'new' template
  #  debugger
  end
  def create
    @movie = Movie.create!(params[:movie])
    flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} was succesfully created."
    redirect_to movies_path
  end
end`# This file is app/controllers/movies_controller.rb
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
  end

  def show
    id = params[:id]
    @movie = Movie.find(id)
    # will render app/views/movies/show.html.haml by default
  end
  def new
    # default render 'new' template
  #  debugger
  end
  def create
    @movie = Movie.create!(params[:movie])
    flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} was succesfully created."
    redirect_to movies_path
  end
end
```

app/views/layouts/application.htlm.halm

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title Rotten Potatoes!
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body
    = yield
```

And the result interpreted is notice the absence of HTML and other tags :

```
<h2>All Movies</h2>
<table id='movies'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Movie Title</th>
      <th>Rating</th>
      <th>Release Date</th>
      <th>More Info</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>EEEe</td>
      <td>G</td>
      <td>2013-02-27 00:00:00 UTC</td>
      <td><a href="/movies/27">More about EEEe</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<a href="/movies/new">Add new movie</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename:

```
app/views/layouts/application.htlm.halm
```

to:

```
app/views/layouts/application.html.haml
```

Comment: Sometimes the simple things are the ones that kill you. Thank you my mistake!!